# Bast Practice to handle a set of attributes/variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered this problem while I was reading the [rails cast on image croping](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast), the original code is like (with irrelevant code removed):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end
end
```

As you can see here, things like :crop_x has been defined and checked four times. This is quite redundant.

Thus I'm thinking I can define an array of symbols instead, like below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  _cropset = :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  _cropset.each {|attr| attr_accessor attr}

  def cropping?
    # How to properly reference to a variable from attribute..?
  end 
end
```

But as you can see.. I got stuck at the comment part above.

I believe it's not a good practice do manually check all these variables as in the code above.. but how should I improve this code, and how to reference to a variable using symbol?

Comment: I personally think that the code that you are referring to is just fine. Instead of creating fancy containers and iterating over the contents you check these four (note, four, not hundreds, etc) values directly.

Comment: @akonsu Thing is.. if next time I want to add in something more, I have to add the checking at two place.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it either as a hash:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop

  # somewhere in the code, `@crop` is set like `{x: foo, y: bar, w: baz, h: bang}`

  def cropping?; @crop.none?{|_, v| v.blank?} end
end
```

or as an array:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :crop

  # somewhere in the code, `@crop` is set like `[x, y, w, h]`

  def cropping?; @crop.none?(&:blank?) end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ary` in argument list to transform an array (or some instance that can be converted to array via `to_a` method) into argument list.

Because that `def` block create new `self` binding environment, you cannot access `_cropset` defined in class environment (where `self` refers to the `User` class) in your `cropping?` instance method (where `self` refers to the actual instance of `User`). You should either define an instance method to return the cropset or make `_cropset` an constant(`CropSet`).

Use [`Object#send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to invoke method identified by symbol in your `cropping?` method. To shorten the `! . &&` chain, you can use [`Enumerable#none?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F), as **sawa** showed. Besides, you can have a look at some other related methods:

- [`Enumerable#all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)
- [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  CropSet = :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  attr_accessor *CropSet

  def cropping?
    CropSet.none?{|m| send(m).blank?}
  end 
end
```

Comment: I would advise against making a non-class/module constant camel case; `CROP_SET` is more conventional.